# Why Chrome maintains scrollTop from previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Chrome maintains the `scrollTop` from previous page.
Eg: I am in list page and scroll down to end of the page and clicked on a record to view. The view record opened in a new page but the scroll position is not on the top.

**Tried and failed:**

1)In `document.ready()` made the `scrollTop as 0`(View page)

2)On `window onunload()` made `scrollTop as 0`(in list page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to the page you are going to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Window event and write page-top over there.

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        //Scroll top code will go here.
    }
```